# CORS Error: Do I need some kind of server for my WebApp to subscribe to a Web Socket Feed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server, cors

I am working with REACT JS and tried to build a little webpage in my **REACT app that connects** to the open **websocket feed** of the crypto currency portal Coinbase in order to display some pushed realtime currency prices.

I tried to open the socket by

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const CryptoFeed = () => {
    const [prices, setPrices] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        debugger;
        const socket = io.connect('wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com');
        //const socket = io.connect('wss://ws-feed.gdax.com'); // I tried gdax too, but its the same error

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('connect');
        });
    }, []);
    return <div>Hallo</div>;
};

export default CryptoFeed;
```

but then I get that error in the chrome (and firefox) console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ws-feed.gdax.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N6s7NQ5' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I started my research and found the CORS topic. And here is my question:

**What is the proper architectural way to display data form a foreign server an my javascript webapp?**

Thank you su much for your answwers.

Comment: Yes it seems like you need to proxy it through some server as they don't support direct embedding atm.

Answer (score 1):

Initial handshake is HTTP before the connection continues in WS protocol. In that initial handshake the GDAX/Coinbase servers are not sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.
Unfortunately, you need to connect to their servers over websocket using your own server, and then your clients/end users has to connect to your server to receive the data live. See this thread below:

https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-pro-node/issues/116#issuecomment-332925708

PS:
When you make a GET/POST request from a browser with `location.hostname` to target domain `resource.com`, it is a bit different from executing curl/wget from linux. In the latter one, you would receive a response regardless of what headers are sent. However, if `resource.com` does not set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, the browser will block the request for security reasons.

Above is important for websockets because websocket connections are initiated with a standard HTTP request that acts as a handshake. After the 1st HTTP request succeeds, the client will send the headers seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#client_handshake_request) to upgrade to websocket. So if the initial HTTP fails because the request was initiated from browser and `resource.com` did not send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, the upgrade to websocket wont work.

This is a good approach (but not enough, authentication/token mechanism is often used also) by websocket servers to prevent someone hosting an html file in a server that would send websocket request to `resource.com`. Because if your server gets 500 simultaneous hits from 500 clients, all your server did was to host and send the html/js, and bulk of the work would be done by `resource.com` by having to serve ws connections to 500 clients. Instead, `resource.com` forces your server to make single ws connection (the server itself from backend) and leaves the rest to you. Now after having the initial ws connection to `resource.com`, your server has to provide websocket connection to those 500 clients and send them the data that it receives. In a way,  it acts as a mirror/amplifier.

I would create memcache/redis to temporarily store price info into ram from the ws connection and fetch them from there and send them to secondary websocket connections that your clients opened to your server. (unless you want to keep the data long term)